# How to use one sql parameter to represent input array

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, oracle, parameters

Is there a way to write sql for Oracle, MS SQL:

```
Select * from table where id in(:arr)


Select * from table where id in(@arr)
```

With one param in sql 'arr' to represent an array of items?
I found examples that explode arr to @arr0,.., @arrn and feed array as n+1 separate parameters, not array, like this

```
Select * from table where id in(:arr0, :arr1, :arr2)


Select * from table where id in(@arr0, @arr1, @arr2)
```

Not what i want.
These will cause change in sql query and this creates new execution plans based on number of parameter.

I ask for .net, c# and Oracle and MS SQL.

Thanks for constructive ideas!

/ip/

Comment: NO, AFAIK there is no way to use a single parameter to represent multiple values. You could explore the [Table Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) approach using a Stored Procedure instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to a **Table Valued Parameter** as Steve mentioned, there are a couple of other techniques available.  For example you can parse a delimited string

**Example**

```
Declare @arr varchar(50) = '10,20,35'

Select A.*
 From  YourTable A
 Join string_split(@arr,',') B on A.ID=value
```

**Or even**

```
Select A.*
 From  YourTable A
 Where ID in ( select value from string_split(@arr,',') )
```

Comment: Well, this is not using parameters and of course the execution plan is ruined as well.

Comment: @Steve Just an alternative ... Perhaps I have a different read than you. :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe Table Value Parameter is good option for this case. Have a look at a sample code below in SQL Server.

```
-- Your table
CREATE TABLE SampleTable
(
    ID          INT
)

INSERT INTO SampleTable VALUES
(1010),
(2010),       
(3010),
(4010),
(5010),      
(6010),      
(7010),      
(8030)
GO

-- Create a TABLE type in SQL database which you can fill from front-end code
CREATE TYPE ParameterTableType AS TABLE  
(
    ParameterID INT
    --, some other columns
)
GO

-- Create a stored proc using table type defined above
CREATE PROCEDURE ParameterArrayProcedure
(
    @ParameterTable AS ParameterTableType READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT
        S.*
    FROM SampleTable S
    INNER JOIN @ParameterTable P ON S.ID = P.ParameterID

END
GO

-- Populated table type variable
DECLARE @ParameterTable AS ParameterTableType
INSERT INTO @ParameterTable (ParameterID) VALUES (1010), (4010), (7010)

EXECUTE ParameterArrayProcedure @ParameterTable

DROP PROCEDURE ParameterArrayProcedure
DROP TYPE ParameterTableType
DROP TABLE SampleTable
GO
```

Apart from Table Value Parameter, you can also use [Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) or [XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-system-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-ver15) values as SQL parameter but yes, it will definitely change your execution plan accordingly.

Comment: @MT0, In C#, you need to create `DataTable` with the same columns defined in TVP and use it as SP parameter. SQL will itself map it with TVP if # of columns and their respective datatype matches.

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle

In other languages (i.e. Java) you can [pass an SQL collection as a bind parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34699771/1509264) and directly use it in an SQL statement.

However, [C# does not support passing SQL collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50485813/1509264) and only supports passing `OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray` ([documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/featOraCommand.htm#BABBDHBB)) which is a PL/SQL only data-type and cannot be used (directly) in SQL statements.

To pass an array, you would need to pass a `PLSQLAssociativeArray` to a PLSQL stored procedure and use that to convert it to an SQL collection that you can use in an SQL statement. An example of a procedure to convert from a PL/SQL associative array to an SQL collection is:

```sql
CREATE TYPE IntList AS TABLE OF INTEGER
/

CREATE PACKAGE tools IS
  TYPE IntMap IS TABLE OF INTEGER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  FUNCTION IntMapToList(
    i_map IntMap
  ) RETURN IntList;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY tools IS
  FUNCTION IntMapToList(
    i_map IntMap
  ) RETURN IntList
  IS
    o_list IntList := IntList();
    i      BINARY_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    IF i_map IS NOT NULL THEN
      i := o_list.FIRST;
      WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
        o_list.EXTEND;
        o_list( o_list.COUNT ) := i_map( i );
        i := i_map.NEXT( i );
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
    RETURN o_list;
  END;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a stringified XML and pass it inside SQL where I convert it to the collection to use in "IN":

```
//rawSql
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    EVENTS
WHERE
    (:EVENTTYPES IS NULL OR EVENT_TYPE IN (SELECT value FROM (SELECT XMLTYPE(:EVENTTYPES) AS xml FROM dual), XMLTABLE('/Values/Value' PASSING xml COLUMNS value NUMBER PATH '.')))

//C#
using (var command = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = rawSql;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    var dbParameter = command.CreateParameter();
    dbParameter.ParameterName = "EVENTTYPES";
    dbParameter.DbType = DbType.String;
    dbParameter.Value = new XElement("Values", from value in new int[] { 1, 2, 3 } select new XElement("Value", value)).ToString();            
    command.Parameters.Add(dbParameter);
}
```